# Why the code in Promise.then() not been called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Why the code in Promise.then() not been called?

I'm writting a server with expressjs and bluebird promise.When I tried to promisify a function using Promise.promisify(), I found that the code I wrote in Promise.then() doesn't work.My codes are as follow

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var test = function(req) {
    console.log('123');
};

var regist=Promise.promisify(test);

app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
    reg.regist()
    .then(function () {
        console.log('456');
    });
```

I post a request to '/test' and only saw 123 printed in the console.How could I make the codes in the Promise.then() work?

Comment: [read the documentation on promisify](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) to gain a better understanding of the bad assumptions you made, and what your code is doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.promisify` creates a mechanism that automatically passes in a callback function as the last argument to your original function. Your function doesn't take a callback function and never calls one, so there's no way for the promise to resolve.

If your function is not asynchronous, there isn't much point in promisifying it, but here's how you could do so:

```js
var test = function(req, callback) {
  console.log('123');

  callback();
};

var regist = Promise.promisify(test);
var request = { someProperty: 'some value'};

regist(request)
  .then(function() {
    console.log('456');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.4.7/bluebird.min.js"></script>
```